# Is the target of MouseEvent always an Element?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Visual Studio Code shows that target variable is of [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) type in the following TypeScript code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let target = event.target
})
```

Why isn't it marked rather as an [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)? Can [CharacterData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData) or [Document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) be also a target of MouseEvent?
I was clicking in the web browser window with the following HTML code, but I was unable to obtain types of EventTarget other than Element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <script>
   document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {  
     let target = event.target
     console.log(target instanceof Element)
   })
 </script>
</head>
<body>
test
</body>
</html>
```

If Visual Studio Code marked target of MouseEvent as Element, then I would be able to write in Typescript:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event.target.matches('.carousel__control--prev'))
    shiftCarouselLeft(event.target.closest('.carousel'))
})
```

But now I have to explicitly cast event.target to Element to call matches() function on it:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let target = <Element>event.target
  if (target.matches('.carousel__control--prev'))
    shiftCarouselLeft(target.closest('.carousel'))
})
```

Comment: What's the issue here?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: I have been wondering if VS Code or TypeScript could work better and thanks to that I could avoid casting: let target = <Element>event.target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any EventTarget can be the target of a MouseEvent event:

```js
const foo = new EventTarget();
foo.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
  console.log('is `foo`', evt.target === foo);
  console.log('is MouseEvent',  evt instanceof MouseEvent);
});
foo.dispatchEvent( new MouseEvent('click') );
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to get mouse event on the whole `Document` node, but not for all events. You can get `Document` node for e.g. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` as [it's shown in the demo](https://codepen.io/Comandeer/pen/yLNVYRw) (works in Chrome, but doesn't work in Firefox or Safari).

It is also theoretically possible to get such event on text node, but AFAIK no browsers do it.